# Redmine - how to configure email sending with postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, sendmail, redmine

I've installed postfix as my smtp server and it works fine, cuz I can send e-mails, for example by typing:

```
sendmail mail@mail.com
```

and e-mail is delivered corectly. But now I would like that redmine would send notifications to     the users. That's my redmine installation info:

```
Environment:
Redmine version                2.5.2.stable
Ruby version                   1.9.3-p547 (2014-05-14) [x86_64-linux]
Rails version                  3.2.19
Environment                    production
Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
Subversion                     1.8.8
Git                            1.9.1
Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
no plugin installed
```

And the configuration.yml:

```
default:
# Outgoing emails configuration (see examples above)
email_delivery:
delivery_method: :sendmail
smtp_settings:
address: 127.0.0.1
port: 25
domain: dev.my-domain.org
authentication: :login
user_name: ""
password: ""
```

After changes of yml file I've restarted apache every time of course. But all the time I'm getting following error when trying to open notifications config page:

> Email delivery is not configured, and notifications are disabled.
>
> Configure your SMTP server in `config/configuration.yml` and restart
>   the application to enable them.

How to deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check if your `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries` is true in config/environment.rb?

Comment: Yes I did, it was set to false, but I switched it to true.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time without understanding why sending option is disabled, I found that setting `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries` to `True` did the trick!

Answer (score -3):

You have to restart all, not only Apache. I did see this issue and i tried with "Restart All"